# How do I install Swift on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I noticed Xcode has released a (non-snapshot) [xCode download for Ubuntu](https://swift.org/download/).

I looked for an article on how to install it and I couldnt find anything.

Can anyone advise how to do this?

Comment: That isn't XCode for Ubuntu, that's Swift for Ubuntu. The XCode link is just saying that Swift is a part of XCode.

Comment: Is Xcode available for ubuntu?

Comment: No http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406151/can-you-run-xcode-in-linux

Comment: Is there a way to buy/download a version of OS X El Capitan to run it in vmware?

Comment: Where to buy/download a version of OSX to run in a VM is a question for Apple, not Ubuntu.

Comment: My brother, from what I know, Apple does not allow/cater for iOS development on non-Macs.
You might just find yourself in legal trouble. Some bloggers claim it's not possible to install Xcode on Ubuntu, but I personally did manage to install it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To install Swift on Ubuntu, you are going to have install a component called clang:

Go to the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

If you installed the Swift toolchain on Linux to a directory other than the system root, you will need to run the following command, using the actual path of your Swift installation:

```
export PATH=/path/to/Swift/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```

You can verify that you are running the expected version of Swift by entering the swift command and passing the --version flag:

```
swift --version
 Apple Swift version 2.2-dev (LLVM ..., Clang ..., Swift ...)
```

The -dev suffix on the version number is used to indicate that it’s a development build, not a released version.