# Can I develop iOS Applications in Ubuntu without using a virtual mac OS system?

Tags: application-development, 18.04, programming, ios

I'm a developer of Android applications and a java programmer. I'm learning IOS programming but I don't have mac OS; I use Ubuntu.

I want way to program IOS apps in Ubuntu without using a virtual machine (in vmware or VirtualBox) And without MacOS.

Can I do that in Ubuntu?

Comment: sorry... but you can't you gonna need xcode which is only for Mac systems.

Comment: IIRC, you can write Swift code without the xcode IDE, as is substantiated by the above link to a possible duplicate answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to have Xcode installed on your machine and that's not possible on Ubuntu.

I have been looking for that for a while and I find these answers to be very informative (read them in order):

1. [Can you run xcode in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406151/can-you-run-xcode-in-linux)
2. [How do I install Xcode on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780609/how-do-i-install-xcode-on-ubuntu)
3. [Can I install xcode in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303013/can-i-install-xcode-in-ubuntu)

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you earned 15 [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have the reputation, don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification. I'll follow that from now on.

Comment: @Melebius, I upvoted his answer because it is very clear, and you don't have to read any more posts. So for me, it is a good answer and he deserves more than 15 reputation for it.

Comment: Thank you @Nulik for your words. I hope I always be concise and explicit as much as possible.